# Why shell does not set a variable which is piped?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a variable which i am trying to set something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

found=0
id=1
echo "Hello" |
while [ $id != 5 ]
do
      id=`expr $id + 1`
      echo $id
      found=1
done

echo "found = $found" // I expect this to be 1
```

Why, and how to set this value?
I am forced to use like this (piped), because the actual code in production environment is:

```
found=0
id=1
my_mount_name="/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount"
echo "select file_system_id, mount_name from SystemTable" | mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3 |
while read file_system_id mount_name
do
   if [ "$id" == "$file_system_id" -a "$my_mount_name" == "$mount_name" ]; then
      echo "Match found for file system ID and mount name"
      found=1
   fi
done
echo "found = $found" // I expect this to be 1, when a match, but does not
```

Comment: This is because the variable is set in a subshell. To have it in the same shell you are working, test other methods. Because in fact, why pipeing after `echo`?

Comment: Are you seeing the message "Match found for file system ID and mount name" when you run it?

Comment: Just now, i got an answer which works, but it is deleted. And in fact it solves the problem.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I wasn't sure that I got your question correctly that's why I've deleted my answer. Have undeleted it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe runs in a subshell.  You can do a few things to make it work, the simplest is:

```
found=0
id=1
my_mount_name="/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount"
echo "select file_system_id, mount_name from SystemTable" | 
mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3 | {
while read file_system_id mount_name
do
   if [ "$id" == "$file_system_id" -a "$my_mount_name" == "$mount_name" ]; then
      echo "Match found for file system ID and mount name"
      found=1
   fi
done
echo "found = $found"; }
# Note the enclosing {}. Inside the black, the variable $found is set.
# After this comment, it will be zero.
```

This technique may require that the enclosing block be fairly large, so you may want to refactor the rest of the script to make this usable.  Another option is to use a fifo or to put the echo/mysql pipeline into a process substitution. (The latter is not portable, but works in bash which may be adequate.)  However, in this particular case, it is probably better to do something like:

```
found=0
id=1
my_mount_name="/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount"

echo "select file_system_id, mount_name from SystemTable" |
mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3 | {
while read file_system_id mount_name
do
   if [ "$id" == "$file_system_id" -a "$my_mount_name" == "$mount_name" ]; then
      echo "Match found for file system ID and mount name"
      exit 0  # Exit the subshell succesfully
   fi
done
exit 1; } && found=1
```

Comment: But `exit` can only return 8 bit or so.  You could also use `do_it_all() { mysql … | while read …; do …; echo "match found"; done; }` and `found=\`do_it_all\`` to get a longer piece of information (like the string `match found` in this case).

Comment: Thanks. Your second code works great, and nice use of exit. Although @hek2mgl code works fine in example, but in actual code somehow it does not.

Comment: Note that this is still a bit weird.  In particular, if mysql generates a log of output and the match is found early, mysql might spit out too much data and end up generating a "pipe closed" error message.  It would probably be cleaner to replace the while loop with  a simple `grep -q "$my_mount_name *mount_name"`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the variables to the sub shell's environemnt:

```
foo=1
bar=2

echo "sds" | foo="$foo" bar="$bar" while ...
```

Comment: Good answer; do you care to add an explanation?

Comment: Thanks for undelete, it worked infact, and i was lucky to catch your answer before you deleted :-)

Comment: @unxnut You can call every shell command like this "ENV_VAR=sds ENV_VAR=DSFSD ... COMMAND"

Comment: @kingsmasher1 However, there are still problems with passing back the `$found` variable I guess. Using environment works only in a single direction

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i upvoted, but although your code works great in the example i put, but in the actual production code for db that i pasted, putting the `found=${found} inside the pipe, makes the code go in infinite wait, so i am accepting the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @fedorqui commented, bash puts pipeline components  in separate subshells, so the changes to your variables disappear when the subshell exits.

There are 2 strategies to deal with this:

1. only use the changed variables in the same subshell

   ```
   echo "Hello" |
   {
       while [ $id != 5 ]
       do
           ((id++))
           echo $id
           found=1
       done
       echo "found = $found" // I expect this to be 1
   }
   ```

   This can be a problem if you have lots of code that relies on those variables
2. replace the pipeline with process substitution. This means that the while loop is not executed in a subshell, it's run in the current shell:

   ```
   while [ $id != 5 ]
   do
       ((id++))
       echo $id
       found=1
   done < <(echo "Hello")
   echo "found = $found" // I expect this to be 1
   ```

   This can suffer from poor readability, but you can put as many newlines inside `<(...)` as you want.

   Your production code rewritten with process substitution (and bash/ksh conditional syntax):

   ```
   found=0
   id=1
   my_mount_name="/opt/insiteone/fuse-mount"

   while read file_system_id mount_name; do
       if [[ $id == $file_system_id ]] && [[ $my_mount_name == $mount_name ]]; then
           echo "Match found for file system ID and mount name"
           found=1
       fi
   done < <(
       echo "select file_system_id, mount_name from SystemTable" | 
       mysql ifm -uroot -pinsite3 
   )
   echo "found = $found"
   ```

Comment: Process substitution will only work in Bash, if you have shebang set to `#!/bin/sh` it won't. Hence your script is not portable.

Comment: ksh also has process substitution. In my experience, portability is over-rated: how many systems do you plan to run your script on? It already relies on mysql

Comment: The existing script using that, and just because of 1 thing added to it, we can't change the shebang variable.

Comment: Only the second proposal suffers from being not-so-portable.  Correct comment (should have been mentioned in the answer) but probably the solution fits OP's need.